# CSS to keep element at "fixed" position on screen

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a trick to create a "fixed" HTML object on the browser screen using CSS. I want it to stay in the same position all the time, even when the user scrolls through the document. I'm not sure what the proper term for this is.

It would be like the chat button on Facebook or the Feedback button that is on some websites that follows you throughout the page.

In my situation, I want to keep a div at the absolute bottom-right corner of the screen at all times. Sample CSS appreciated.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You may be looking for [`position: fixed`.](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html)

Works everywhere except IE6 and many mobile devices.

Comment: @MichaelJCalkins I have, and it was awesome!

Answer (score 52):

The easiest way is to use `position: fixed`:

```
.element {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#choose-position

(note that position fixed is buggy / doesn't work on ios and android browsers)

Answer (score 17):

Make sure your content is kept in a `div`, say divfix.

```
<div id="divfix">Your Code goes here</div>
```

CSS :

```
#divfix {
       bottom: 0;
       right: 0;
       position: fixed;
       z-index: 3000;
}
```

Hope ,It will help you..

Answer (score 9):

```
position: sticky;
```

The sticky element sticks on top of the page (top: 0) when you reach its scroll position.

See example:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_sticky

Comment: OP asked for content to remain visible at bottom-right at all times. To the best of my knowledge, sticky doesn't allow that.

Comment: > I want it to stay in the same position all the time, even when the user scrolls through the document.

Answer (score 3):

The tweak:

```
position:fixed;
```

works, **but** it breaks certain options....for example a scrollable menu that is tagged with a fixed position will not expand with the browser window anymore...wish there was another way to pin something on top/always visible

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
p.pos_fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:30px;
    right:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`position: fixed;`

Will make this happen.

It handles like `position:absolute;` with the exception that it will scroll with the window as the user scrolls down the content.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
#mydiv {
    position: fixed; 
    height: 30px; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
}
```

This will create a `div`, that will be fixed on top of your screen. - [fixed](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html)

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep floating text in the same location over an image when changing browser zoom, I used this CSS:

```
position: absolute;
margin-top: -18%
```

I think the % instead of fixed pixels is what does it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
#fixedbutton {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px; 
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

The `z-index` is added to overshadow any element with a greater property you might not know about.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="fixedbtn"><button type="button" value="Delete"></button></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#fixedbtn{
 position: fixed;
 margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
 width: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
<div style="top: 0; position: sticky;">your code</div>
```

or you can add class/id like this:

**html:**

```
<div class="FixedPosition">your code</div>
```

**css:**

```
.FixedPosition{
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
}
```

you may change the "top" if you want it to not be on top of the screen and don't delete the top else it won't work.

I hope this help : )