# "Lock" div in the right position when user scrolls vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I've been looking for exactly this exactly this navigation in my project: http://www.karalienesmortosmokykla.lt

When the user scrolls even a little bit it automatically 'lock' in the right position of the div with the elements inside.
Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS to keep element at "fixed" position on screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576342/css-to-keep-element-at-fixed-position-on-screen)

Answer (score 2):

i think position: fixed should do it.

Comment: If I use position fixed the scroll stop working, just keep the first div on the screen and disable the navigation