# How can I make a table move with the page as the user scrolls up or down?

Tags: html, css, html-table

This is currently what I have for a table, is there a way that I can make this table move with the page as the user scrolls up or down?

```
<table width="800" border="1" cell="" spacing="2" bgcolor="#336699">
    <tr>
        <th width="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Name</th>
        <th width="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Toll Free Number</th>
        <th width="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Toll Free Number International</th>
        <th width="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Conference ID</th>
        <th width="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Moderator Pin</th>
    </tr>
    <!-- more -->
</table>
```

Comment: Your question is not related to Perl, but rather to HTML and CSS. I'm going to change your tags and edit the question accordingly.

Comment: If you want to look for a solution yourself, do not thing about _tables_, think about _elements_ instead. You want an element in the page to _stick_ to the screen at the same position even if you scroll. That sounds like _making an element sticky_. :)

Comment: I think you are right, that seems like more of what I am looking for, I just did not really know how to phrase my question, thank you though I'll try that!

Comment: In the spirit of these comments... [CSS Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: @simbabque looks like OP wants to make the table not sticky: "make this table move with the page as the user scrolls up or down". Or I miss something? BTW this is the natural behaviour of any element in an html page.

Comment: @J.Daxter will you show us something more about the page? This is just the markup of a table.

Comment: Lelio Faieta, would I make the table not sticky in the table tag?

Comment: I can't really show more without the code looking confusing, the page is basically a calendar and I want a table of information to move with the cursor as the user scrolls up and down the calendar.

Comment: the normal behaviour for an html page is to scroll all the body as you would like. That's why I am telling you we need to see more about the html of the page and the css that you eventually applied to the table to help you. There is not a "sticky" option in the table tag

Answer (score 0):

This question can help you figure out what's going on: [CSS to keep element at "fixed" position on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576342/css-to-keep-element-at-fixed-position-on-screen)
Basically, as someone also commented, you want to think about an element to add to the table. Here's something that works:

```
<table width="800" border="1" cell="" spacing="2" bgcolor="#336699">
        <tr>
            <th width="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Name</th>
            <th width="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Toll Free Number</th>
            <th width="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Toll Free Number International</th>
            <th width="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Conference ID</th>
            <th width="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Moderator Pin</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- more -->
    </table>
    <div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
  height: 4000px;
}

table{
  position:fixed;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xzyvsx00/

Comment: op wants the opposite

Comment: @LelioFaieta I see now, the comments hadn't updated while I wrote my answer. Though to be fair, the jury is still out on what op wants :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't use CSS at all it is enough for you to setup a "normal" html page to get your desired behaviuour:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1>some content</h1>
        <p>some other content</p>
        <div>
            <table width="800" border="1" cell="" spacing="2" bgcolor="#336699">
                <tr>
                    <th width="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Name</th>
                    <th width="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Toll Free Number</th>
                    <th width="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Toll Free Number International</th>
                    <th width="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Conference ID</th>
                    <th width="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Moderator Pin</th>
                </tr>
        <!-- more -->
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will make the table scroll with the rest of the page. So if it doesn't you have somewhere in the page a css definition to make it sticky

Answer (score 0):

You can set your table to `position:fixed` on your CSS. This makes the element positioned relative to the viewport.

If you don't have a CSS file your code would be something like this:

```
<table width="800" border="1" cell="" spacing="2" bgcolor="#336699" style="position:fixed;">
    <tr>
        <th width="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Name</th>
        <th width="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Toll Free Number</th>
        <th width="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Toll Free Number International</th>
        <th width="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Conference ID</th>
        <th width="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Moderator Pin</th>
    </tr>
<!-- more -->
</table>
```

I recommend checking this tutorial to better understand about basic positioning: http://learnlayout.com