# section being inside a fixed nav bar not shown with the position "fixed"

Tags: html, css

I started my last project on a course freecodecamp, which is building a portfolio but i got stuck when setting a `navbar` to be fixed somehow my section content get hidden and wraped inside the fixed `navbar` only when i remove position "fixed" it shoes on regular order.
What i want is to have a fixed `navbar` with a section that have a background image and a header for now.

**Here is my code:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navbar {
  /*if you set remove the mav bar fixed the content gets all weird  position: fixed; */
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #BE3144;
  height: 100px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  ;
}

#navbar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: xx-large;
  margin-right: 35px;
  color: #F0F0F0;
}

#navbar li:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

#welcome-section {
  background: url(https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/gray-painted-background_53876-94041.jpg?w=2000);
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav id="navbar">
    <ul class="container">
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="">about</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="">work</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <section id="welcome-section">
    <h1>i am mohamed <br>a web developer</h1>
  </section>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the css tag `position: fixed`

Also, you shouldn't use the `<ul>` and `<li>` as it is depricated

Before you create a question, please look through our tens of thousands of ready answers, [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576342/css-to-keep-element-at-fixed-position-on-screen)!

Comment: ul and li elements are not deprecated

Comment: `position: fixed` is a CSS declaration, not a tag

Comment: thanks for the reply,i knew about the position fixed and i searched through the questions but my probleme is when i set the "navbar" into position fixed the section content below it dosent show thats my probleme not how to fix a nav bar with only htmls and css